# dojo calendar pop-up

Tags: javascript, dojo

How do I implement a dojo datepicker in dojo version 1.8 ?
This should be different from a dojo DateTextBox in the way that a dropdown calendar is displayed on clicking a calendar icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to looking for [dijit/TooltipDialog](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/TooltipDialog) and require a few of dijit like `"dijit/popup", "dijit/Calendar"`

or `"dijit/form/DropDownButton" ,"dijit/Calendar"`

[Look at here will easier.](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/sz7BX/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `"dijit/CalendarLite"` and by css and some javascript coding you can make DatePicker different from `dijit/form/DateTextBox`.